# android two threads with one delay

Tags: android, multithreading

i hope you can help me. I need two loops. they must run at the same time and one loop need a delay. The first loop must create ImageViews in a Array and the second must get the location on the views. I know it must create with Threads but how ? Or give it a other way ?

```
public ImageView[] bubbles = new ImageView[];

public void create_bubbles() throws InterruptedException {


    RelativeLayout game_layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.game_layout){

        ThreadForLoopA threadA = new ThreadForLoopA();
        ThreadForLoopB threadB = new ThreadForLoopB();

        threadA.start();
        threadB.start();

    }

}

public class ThreadForLoopA extends Thread{

    float posX = 10;
    float posY = 10;

    @Override
    public void run(){

            for(int i=0;;i++){


        bubbles[i] = new ImageView(null);
        bubbles[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.unbenannt);
        game_layout.addView(bubbles[i], 100, 100);
        setPos(posX, posY, bubbles[i]);
        posX = posX + 100;

        if(i == 5){
            break;
        }

        }



    }
}


public class ThreadForLoopB extends Thread{

    @Override
    public void run(){
        for(int i = 0 ; ; i++){

            float location;
            location = bubbles[i].getY();
            if(i == 5){

                break;

            }

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Right way to do would be to post it to the view. You have the logic of retrieving the location there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can postDelayed from a Handler, but for your case, you must start your ThreadB after ThreadA finish, otherwise you will not get values.

For delayed execution:

```
   RelativeLayout game_layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.game_layout){

    ThreadForLoopA threadA = new ThreadForLoopA();
    final ThreadForLoopB threadB = new ThreadForLoopB();

    threadA.start();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
         threadB.start();
    }}, 5000);//5 seconds

}
```

Comment: can you ride me a example in my code with a handler ?

Comment: i must add a semicolon at the end of findViewById(R.id.game_layout);

Comment: and the problem is the B thread dont wait 5 seconds. and if i add 50000 ms the thread wait but after the time the thread dont wait

Comment: No, this is scheduled to start in 50000ms, it will not wait again. You can use Thread.sleep(5000) for that

Comment: and this is what i need. where i must add this ?

Comment: instead of the break at your if(i == 5)